# How to determine if website has more than one platform?

Tags: html, wordpress

Someone built my website using I think html5 and wordpress.  How can I get into the codes to find out?? Another website designer is trying to charge me a lot of money to diagnose this??

Comment: Look at the source.  If you don't know the difference between PHP code and HTML5 learn the difference.

Comment: Find another **web designer** please.

Answer (score 1):

This question would appear to be badly worded - specifically I can't see what a platform would have to do with it - you may want to fix up the header.

There is more then 1 way to work something like this out.

The most straight forward way if you are not very technical would be approach your hosting provider and ask them for details to get into the site.  Advise them of the nature of the problem (ie you don't know exactly what you need, but can they advise you of any of the following - 
1.  FTP details for the account (you may need to ask them to reset it)
2.  CPanel and/or  PHPMyAdmin and/or any other account details they may 
    have.

Once you have this, you will be able to log in and have a look, - or get someone else to do this.

(If you have FTP access, log in with FTP, download the source code to the site and have a look at it - note that if you have a database associated with it, FTP will probably not download the database, you will need to get a dump of it if you are planning on moving - this can often be done with PHPMyAdmin, in the application or even by uploading and running a script).

Also, there is no prohibition against posting a website address here and asking us to look at it and see if we can determine what it is.  A lot of programs have signatures and hints which would allow a clued up person to provide a partial or full answer.  (Don't go posting usernames and passwords though)